# Get data points from Seaborn distplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I use

```
sns.distplot
```

to plot a univariate distribution of observations. Still, I need not only the chart, but also the data points. How do I get the data points from matplotlib Axes (returned by distplot)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the [matplotlib.patches API](https://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html). For instance, to get the first line:

```
sns.distplot(x).get_lines()[0].get_data()
```

This returns two numpy arrays containing the x and y values for the line.

For the bars, information is stored in:

```
sns.distplot(x).patches
```

You can access the bar's height via the function [`patches.get_height()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html):

```
[h.get_height() for h in sns.distplot(x).patches]
```

Comment: This is not strictly reliable.  If there were any lines on the `Axes` before the call to `distplot` you will get the data from that line.

Comment: Another tip: to get the bin left edges, widths as well as the heights do:
`l = [[h.xy[0], h.get_width(), h.get_height()] for h in sns.distplot(x).patches]`

Comment: I have just tested the solution and it does not work for me as 'get_lines()' is not a valid method for a FacetGrid Object. I have succeeded using this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46248348/seaborn-matplotlib-how-to-access-line-values-in-facetgrid

Answer (score 7):

If you want to obtain the kde values of an histogram you can use **scikit-learn** `KernelDensity` function instead:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity

ds=pd.read_csv('data-to-plot.csv')
X=ds.loc[:,'Money-Spent'].values[:, np.newaxis]


kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.75).fit(X) #you can supply a bandwidth
                                                              #parameter. 

x=np.linspace(0,5,100)[:, np.newaxis]

log_density_values=kde.score_samples(x)
density=np.exp(log_density_values)

array([1.88878660e-05, 2.04872903e-05, 2.21864649e-05, 2.39885206e-05,
       2.58965064e-05, 2.79134003e-05, 3.00421245e-05, 3.22855645e-05,
       3.46465903e-05, 3.71280791e-05, 3.97329392e-05, 4.24641320e-05,
       4.53246933e-05, 4.83177514e-05, 5.14465430e-05, 5.47144252e-05,
       5.81248850e-05, 6.16815472e-05, 6.53881807e-05, 6.92487062e-05,
       7.32672057e-05, 7.74479375e-05, 8.17953578e-05, 8.63141507e-05,
       ..........................
       ..........................
       3.93779919e-03, 4.15788216e-03, 4.38513011e-03, 4.61925890e-03,
       4.85992626e-03, 5.10672757e-03, 5.35919187e-03, 5.61677855e-03])
```

Comment: Probably `density=np.exp(log_density_values)` and not `density=np.exp(log_density)`

Answer (score 3):

With the newer version of seaborn this is not the case anymore. First of all, distplot has been replaced with displot. Secondly, when calling get_lines() an error message comes up AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'get_lines'.

Comment: `displot` now returns a `FacetGrid`, you have to access individual axes of the `FacetGrid` to access their `lines` or `patches` attributes. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75721847/13636407

Answer (score 0):

This will  get the kde curve you want

```
line = sns.distplot(data).get_lines()[0]
plt.plot(line.get_xdata(), line.get_ydata())
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).