# Seaborn/Matplotlib: how to access line values in FacetGrid?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to shade the area between two lines in a Seaborn FacetGrid. The `fill_between` method will do this, but I need to access the values of each line in each subplot to pass them in.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = [{'Change': 0.0,  'Language': 'Algonquin',  'Type': 'Mother tongue',  'Year': '2011'}, {'Change': 0.0,  'Language': 'Algonquin',  'Type': 'Spoken at home',  'Year': '2011'}, {'Change': -21.32,  'Language': 'Algonquin',  'Type': 'Mother tongue',  'Year': '2016'}, {'Change': -34.84,  'Language': 'Algonquin',  'Type': 'Spoken at home',  'Year': '2016'}, {'Change': 0.0,  'Language': 'Atikamekw',  'Type': 'Mother tongue',  'Year': '2011'}, {'Change': 0.0,  'Language': 'Atikamekw',  'Type': 'Spoken at home',  'Year': '2011'}, {'Change': 5.41,  'Language': 'Atikamekw',  'Type': 'Mother tongue',  'Year': '2016'}, {'Change': 19.15,  'Language': 'Atikamekw',  'Type': 'Spoken at home',  'Year': '2016'}, {'Change': 0.0,  'Language': 'Blackfoot',  'Type': 'Mother tongue',  'Year': '2011'}, {'Change': 0.0,  'Language': 'Blackfoot',  'Type': 'Spoken at home',  'Year': '2011'}, {'Change': -1.4,  'Language': 'Blackfoot',  'Type': 'Mother tongue',  'Year': '2016'}, {'Change': 61.42,  'Language': 'Blackfoot',  'Type': 'Spoken at home',  'Year': '2016'}, {'Change': 0.0,  'Language': 'Carrier',  'Type': 'Mother tongue',  'Year': '2011'}, {'Change': 0.0,  'Language': 'Carrier',  'Type': 'Spoken at home',  'Year': '2011'}, {'Change': -20.38,  'Language': 'Carrier',  'Type': 'Mother tongue',  'Year': '2016'}, {'Change': -18.91,  'Language': 'Carrier',  'Type': 'Spoken at home',  'Year': '2016'}, {'Change': 0.0,  'Language': 'Chilcotin',  'Type': 'Mother tongue',  'Year': '2011'}, {'Change': 0.0,  'Language': 'Chilcotin',  'Type': 'Spoken at home',  'Year': '2011'}, {'Change': -13.82,  'Language': 'Chilcotin',  'Type': 'Mother tongue',  'Year': '2016'}, {'Change': 7.41,  'Language': 'Chilcotin',  'Type': 'Spoken at home',  'Year': '2016'}, {'Change': 0.0,  'Language': 'Cree languages',  'Type': 'Mother tongue',  'Year': '2011'}, {'Change': 0.0,  'Language': 'Cree languages',  'Type': 'Spoken at home',  'Year': '2011'}, {'Change': -11.52,  'Language': 'Cree languages',  'Type': 'Mother tongue',  'Year': '2016'}, {'Change': 6.57,  'Language': 'Cree languages',  'Type': 'Spoken at home',  'Year': '2016'}]

langs = pd.DataFrame(data)
g = sns.FacetGrid(langs, col='Language', hue='Type', col_wrap = 4, size=2)
g.map(plt.plot, 'Year', 'Change').set_titles('{col_name}')
g.set(xticks=[2011, 2016], yticks = [-40, 0, 70] )
```

This results in a chart like this:
[image]

Now how do I access the values of each line? I'm guessing something with `g.axes`, but nothing in the docs is helping.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flat axes array of FacetGrid then get all lines of an axis object by `ax.lines`. Iterate over these lines with calls of `get_xdata, get_ydata` to request data of a line than do what you want with these data.
Sample code:

```
...
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    print (ax.lines)
    for line in ax.lines:
        print (line.get_xdata())
        print (line.get_ydata())
```

Output of your code data:

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x10c5facc0>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x10c5fa940>]
['2011' '2016']
[  0.   -21.32]
['2011' '2016']
[  0.   -34.84]
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x10c39a160>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x10c5a4828>]
['2011' '2016']
[ 0.    5.41]
['2011' '2016']
[  0.    19.15]
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x10c5ff6d8>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x10c67c630>]
['2011' '2016']
[ 0.  -1.4]
['2011' '2016']
[  0.    61.42]
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x10c637358>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x10c65ada0>]
['2011' '2016']
[  0.   -20.38]
['2011' '2016']
[  0.   -18.91]
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x10c613668>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x10c6134e0>]
['2011' '2016']
[  0.   -13.82]
['2011' '2016']
[ 0.    7.41]
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x10c5ffd30>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x10c4f5dd8>]
['2011' '2016']
[  0.   -11.52]
['2011' '2016']
[ 0.    6.57]
```

Comment: This is very handy, thank you. While waiting for an answer, I also found that the data values can be accessed via `get_children()` and `get_data()` in each ax, but your solution is far more succinct.

Answer (score 3):

Extending on [@Serenity's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46250091/2137255). Using line information `get_xdata, get_ydata` you can use `fill_between` like

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(langs, col='Language', hue='Type', col_wrap=4, size=3)
g.map(plt.plot, 'Year', 'Change').set_titles('{col_name}')
g.set(xticks=[2011, 2016], yticks = [-40, 0, 70] )
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.fill_between(ax.lines[0].get_xdata().astype(int),
                    ax.lines[0].get_ydata(0), ax.lines[1].get_ydata(),
                    facecolor='#ffdec1')
```

[image]