# Unable to read data from kdeplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a `pandas` dataframe with two columns, A and B, named `df` in the following bits of code.

And I try to plot a kde for each value of B like so:

```py
import seaborn as sbn, numpy as np, pandas as pd

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7.5))
sbn.kdeplot(data=df, x="A", hue="B", fill=True)
fig.savefig("test.png")
```

I read the following propositions but only those where I compute the kde from scratch using `statsmodel` or some other module get me somewhere:
[Seaborn/Matplotlib: how to access line values in FacetGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46248348/seaborn-matplotlib-how-to-access-line-values-in-facetgrid)
[Get data points from Seaborn distplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374983/get-data-points-from-seaborn-distplot)

For curiosity's sake, I would like to know why I am unable to get something from the following code:

```py
kde = sns.kdeplot(data=df, x="A", hue="B", fill=True)
line = kde.lines[0]
x, y = line.get_data()
print(x, y)
```

The error I get is `IndexError: list index out of range`. `kde.lines` has a length of `0`.

Accessing the lines through `fig.axes[0].lines[0]` also raises an `IndexError`.

All in all, I think I tried everything proposed in the previous threads (I tried switching to `displot` instead of using `kdeplot` but this is the same story, only that I have to access axes differently, note `displot` and not `distplot` because it is deprecated), but every time I get to `.get_lines()`, `ax.lines`, ... what is returned is an empty list. So I can't get any values out of it.

**EDIT** : Reproducible example

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, seaborn as sbn

# 1. Generate random data
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B"])

for i in [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, 15, 17, 20, 40, 50]:
    for _ in range(10):
        df = df.append({"A": np.random.random() * i, "B": i}, ignore_index=True)

# 2. Plot data
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7.5))
sbn.kdeplot(data=df, x="A", hue="B", fill=True)

# 3. Read data (error)
ax = fig.axes[0]
x, y = ax.lines[0].get_data()
print(x, y)
```

Comment: Works for me using one of the seaborn examples. Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: I added an example with random data. Tested it myself and I get the same errors than with my original data. Maybe I'm missing something or not plotting as I should.

Comment: `fill=True` now creates a polygon.  A workaround is to create the `kdeplot` a second time with `fill=False` (optionally setting the linecolor to `'none'`). Or you could call `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because using `fill=True` changes the object that matplotlib draws.

When no fill is used, lines are plotted:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7.5))
ax = sbn.kdeplot(data=df, x="A", hue="B")
print(ax.lines)
# [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x000001F365EF7848>, etc.]
```

when you use fill, it changes them to [PolyCollection](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection) objects

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7.5))
ax = sbn.kdeplot(data=df, x="A", hue="B", fill=True)
print(ax.collections)
# [<matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection object at 0x0000016EE13F39C8>, etc.]
```

You could draw the kdeplot a second time, but with `fill=False` so that you have access to the line objects