# Annotation changing the plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, plot-annotations

Usually when I plot some distribution I like to insert auxiliar lines to show extra information, such as mean:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
h = r1['TAXA_ATUAL_UP'].mean()
plt.axvline(h, color='k', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2)
print(h) # 692.6621026418171
plt.annotate('{0:.2f}'.format(h), xy=(h+100, 0.02), fontsize=12)

sns.distplot(r1['TAXA_ATUAL_UP'].dropna())
sns.distplot(r1[r1['REMOTO'] == 1]['TAXA_ATUAL_UP'].dropna(), hist=False, label='Y = 1')
sns.distplot(r1[r1['REMOTO'] == 0]['TAXA_ATUAL_UP'].dropna(), hist=False, label='Y = 0')
```

[image]

Recently, using the same code to plot other data, I got a weird result. Basically, what I notice is that the `h` value is big and the result is that the plot is reduced drastically:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
h = r1['TAXA_ATUAL_DOWN'].mean()
plt.axvline(h, color='k', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2)
print(h) # 8777.987291627895
plt.annotate('{0:.2f}'.format(h), xy=(h, 0.02), fontsize=12)

sns.distplot(r1['TAXA_ATUAL_DOWN'].dropna())
sns.distplot(r1[r1['REMOTO'] == 1]['TAXA_ATUAL_DOWN'].dropna(), hist=False, label='Y = 1')
```

[image]

I wonder what causes this I how I should get the annotation to work properly, or fix whaterver I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
plt.annotate('{0:.2f}'.format(h), xy=(h, 0.02), fontsize=12)
```

with

```
plt.annotate('{0:.2f}'.format(h), xy=(h+100, 0.00012), fontsize=12)
```

I believe what is happening is that you are trying to annotate at the same `xy` coordinates as in your old plot, but the axis scales are drastically different. So when you annotate at `xy=(h,0.02)`, 0.02 is significantly above the maximum of your y axis, and your figure is being re-scaled accordingly.

Looking at your new plot, it looks like it would make more sense to put your text at somewhere like `xy=(h+100, 0.00012)`, or somewhere thereabouts. If that works, you can fine-tune your location according to where you want it (or, more programmatically, put your y coordinate at something like `0.75 * maximum_y_value`, where `maximum_y_value` is the highest point on your y axis).

A hacky but effective way to do this would be to use

```
y_max = max([h.get_height() for h in sns.distplot(r1[r1['REMOTO'] == 1]['TAXA_ATUAL_DOWN'].dropna()).patches])

plt.annotate('{0:.2f}'.format(h), xy=(h, 0.75*y_max), fontsize=12)
```

What this actually does is get the values of the histogram that would be plotted by default in `sns.distplot` (which you have disabled), and finds the max of that.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I can get the maximum_y_value in the measure used by the plots? I mean, maximum_y_value = r1['TAXA_ATUAL_DOWN'].max() do not produce the desired output since I'm plotting a distribution.

Comment: From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374983/get-data-points-from-seaborn-distplot) answer, I believe you would be able to get it like this: `max([h.get_height() for h in sns.distplot(r1[r1['REMOTO'] == 1]['TAXA_ATUAL_DOWN'].dropna().patches])`, or figure out a nicer mathematical way of doing it. FYI, my way would be an approximation, but it should be accurate enough for what you're doing with it.