# Retrieving line data from multiple weighted seaborn distribution plots?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, distribution

I have the code below with randomly generated dataframes and I would like to extract the x and y values of both plotted lines. These line plots show the Price on the Y-axis and are Volume weighted.

For some reason, the line values for the second distribution plot, cannot be stored on the variables "df_2_x", "df_2_y". The values of "df_1_x", "df_1_y" are also written on the other variables. Both print statements return True, so the arrays are completely equal.

If I put them in separate cells in a notebook, it does work.

I also looked at this solution: [How to retrieve all data from seaborn distribution plot with mutliple distributions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52517145/how-to-retrieve-all-data-from-seaborn-distribution-plot-with-mutliple-distributi)

But this does not work for weighted distplots.

```py
import pandas as pd
import random
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Price_1 = [round(random.uniform(2,12), 2) for i in range(30)]
Volume_1 = [round(random.uniform(100,3000)) for i in range(30)]
Price_2 = [round(random.uniform(0,10), 2) for i in range(30)]
Volume_2 = [round(random.uniform(100,1500)) for i in range(30)]

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Price_1' : Price_1,
                    'Volume_1' : Volume_1})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Price_2' : Price_2,
                    'Volume_2' :Volume_2})

df_1_x, df_1_y = sns.distplot(df_1.Price_1, hist_kws={"weights":list(df_1.Volume_1)}).get_lines()[0].get_data()
df_2_x, df_2_y = sns.distplot(df_2.Price_2, hist_kws={"weights":list(df_2.Volume_2)}).get_lines()[0].get_data()

print((df_1_x == df_2_x).all())
print((df_1_y == df_2_y).all())
```

Why does this happen, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not `weight` is used, doesn't make a difference here.
The principal problem is that you are extracting again the first curve in `df_2_x, df_2_y = sns.distplot(df_2....).get_lines()[0].get_data()`. You'd want the second curve instead: `df_2_x, df_2_y = sns.distplot(df_2....).get_lines()[1].get_data()`.

Note that seaborn isn't really meant to concatenate commands. Sometimes it works, but it usually adds a lot of confusion.   E.g. `sns.distplot` returns an `ax` (which represents a subplot). Graphical elements such as lines are added to that `ax`.

Also note that `sns.distplot` has been deprecated. It will be removed from Seaborn in one of the next versions. It is replaced by `sns.histplot` and `sns.kdeplot`.

Here is how the code could look like:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Price_1 = [round(random.uniform(2, 12), 2) for i in range(30)]
Volume_1 = [round(random.uniform(100, 3000)) for i in range(30)]
Price_2 = [round(random.uniform(0, 10), 2) for i in range(30)]
Volume_2 = [round(random.uniform(100, 1500)) for i in range(30)]

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Price_1': Price_1,
                     'Volume_1': Volume_1})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Price_2': Price_2,
                     'Volume_2': Volume_2})

ax = sns.histplot(x=df_1.Price_1, weights=list(df_1.Volume_1), bins=10, kde=True, kde_kws={'cut': 3})
sns.histplot(x=df_2.Price_2, weights=list(df_2.Volume_2), bins=10, kde=True, kde_kws={'cut': 3}, ax=ax)

df_1_x, df_1_y = ax.lines[0].get_data()
df_2_x, df_2_y = ax.lines[1].get_data()

# use fill_between to demonstrate where the extracted curves lie
ax.fill_between(df_1_x, 0, df_1_y, color='b', alpha=0.2)
ax.fill_between(df_2_x, 0, df_2_y, color='r', alpha=0.2)
plt.show()
```

[image: extracting curves from sns.histplot]