# Get data points from Seaborn 'displot()'

Tags: python, seaborn, displot

How can I retrieve arrays containing bin ranges and counts from a `sns.displot()`? I found [older posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374983/get-data-points-from-seaborn-distplot/74786425#74786425) relating to the previous `distplot()` which do not seem to be applicable anymore.

Comment: You can use `np.histogram(..., bins='auto')` to get bin ranges and corresponding counts.

Comment: [seaborn: Can I access the results of seaborn’s statistical transformations?](https://seaborn.pydata.org/faq.html#statistical-inquiries)

Answer (score 1):

For a displot with `kind='kde'` you will find the data under each ax `.lines` attribute.

For a displot with `kind='hist'` you will find the data under each ax `.patches` attribute.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")

g = sns.displot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", kind="kde", lw=8)
ax = g.axes[0, 0]  # loop if multiple axes
line = ax.lines[0]  # loop if multiple lines
x, y = line.get_data()

# Confirm by plotting over
ax.plot(x, y, "r.")

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting overlay plot]

---

You can also do it for `kind=hist`, but as said in the comments there is no point getting values from the plot ; if you want values, use functions that return values.

Still, below an example on how to do it, but **do not rely on it** and instead get values directly from `numpy.histogram`:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")

column = "flipper_length_mm"
x = penguins[column]

# With numpy
bin_edges = np.histogram_bin_edges(
    penguins["flipper_length_mm"],
    range=(np.nanmin(x), np.nanmax(x)),
    bins=10,
)
histogram, bin_edges = np.histogram(x, bins=bin_edges)

# With seaborn
g = sns.displot(data=penguins, x=column, kind="hist", bins=bin_edges)
ax = g.axes[0, 0]  # loop if multiple axes
rectangles = ax.patches

rectangles_x = np.array([r.get_x() for r in rectangles])
rectangles_width = np.array([r.get_width() for r in rectangles])
rectangles_height = np.array([r.get_height() for r in rectangles])

# See here, might be cases where this is not the correct formula
bin_edges_retrieved = np.array([*rectangles_x, rectangles_x[-1] + rectangles_width[-1]])

assert np.allclose(bin_edges, bin_edges_retrieved)
assert np.allclose(histogram, rectangles_height)
```

Comment: I am using your code with kind = "hist" and .patches instead of .lines.
But I am getting "AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no attribute 'get_data"

Comment: You can’t extract the individual data points for hist

Comment: This is also why we don’t answer questions without a complete [mre].

Comment: I am not looking for individual data points as in the proposed solution above. I am looking for the bin ranges and counts in a histogram using displot(). That should be possible?

Comment: @mrClean it is not, as per the link in the comment to your question.

Comment: Actually it is still possible, see edit, but not reliable, and as @TrentonMcKinney said, you should use other functions to get values.